# Pinterest invite Facebook friends functionality is impossible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pinterest, facebook-invite-friends

If you connect to Pinterest with Facebook, it has multiple dialogs that show your complete list of friends (including those not using Pinterest) asking you to invite them.  One is on the front page, and there is another at http://www.pinterest.com/find_friends/

This type of menu is only supposed to be possible for games that use Canvas by using the taggable_friends API, not for a website.

I see multiple questions here asking about how to do exactly what Pinterest is doing, but the response always seems to be it is impossible, the only supported way is to use the Send dialog (for a website not an app/game anyway).

It seems like they got some special permissions before from this thread: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/146850488822600
Is their current build just another special permissions thing?  I haven't been able to find anything stating that they have special permission, and it would be nice to confirm that considering it's not very convincing to say it's impossible when there's a high profile example of it.

I don't want the list to spam their friends, I still want to go through the Send dialog but it would nice to show a list of people that they can invite in a format that is shared with other social sites we have integration with.

Comment: How to invite people are described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Comment: @WizKid I've seen that documentation and understand it, but it doesn't cover anything that seems to support how Pinterest is doing theirs. So whether that is possible through some undocumented way is what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: The bug you link to say: "This functionality is whitelisted for a very few apps and unfortunately we dont whitelist any other apps now". Do you think they are lying for you?

Comment: Well I'm not asking about putting multiple recipients in the Send dialog, I just thought it was related that they have special permission to do some things apparently, but I can't find anywhere that mentions the functionality in my question.

Comment: There is nothing you can do. Just use the normal Send dialog

Comment: You can achieve this by explicitly calling the v1.0 API.  The calls to this will be automatically rerouted to the v2.0 API in April but it works for now.  Maybe Pinterest is doing that, who knows.

Comment: If the app was created after 4/30/2014 there is no way to use v1.0.

Comment: It's already november 2015 and Pinterest is still doing this. We haven't figured out this too... They somehow already know friends uniq ids before opening send dialog. Their ids comes from server-side, leaving us only guessing, how they managed to get them.